# BesselJ Expansion of Cos(x)

Tags: calculus

I have been working on the Bessel series on trigonometric functions, the following is due to E Harris
$$\cos (2 z)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n (2 n+1) \left(2 n^2+2 n+1\right) \left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2 z}} J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(z)\right){}^2$$
and I get
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2 (-1)^{2 n} J_n\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) \left((2 n+1) J_n\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)-z J_{n+1}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)}{1-4 n^2}+J_0\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) \left(J_0\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)-z J_1\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)$$
it would be possible to reduce the second series to the first using difference relations,
I forget to comment the second gives  double precision.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: using the recurrence formula for BesselJ to get similar formulation of  E harris formula ( the first series ) but I do not  get anything similar..